# Rhythmbox - won't play .wav files off of some newer CDs

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, cd

My Rhythmbox won't play (or even list) some of my .wav files. The ones I tried are taken from more recent CDs (one was from 2013). A screen message was displayed saying I need a "demuxer" to play those files but it was unable to find software for this. Is there a way to fix this or another Ubuntu audio player which can play .wav files from all CDs?

Here are the errors:

"**Unable to play file. Advanced Streaming Format (ASF) demuxer is required to play the file, but is not installed. (Cancel/Find In Ubuntu Software)**"

and:

"**Unable to Find Requested Software**"

The .wav files are on my PC hard drive but are directly from original retail purchased CDs. The pattern seems to be files taken from CDs I purchased in about the last four years, regardless of the original release date of the music. E.g. I can play the track "Broken Leg" by Bluejuice, which was released in 2009, but not the track "Survivor", by Destiny's Child, which was released in 2001 but which I purchased in 2019.

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try going to Edit > Preferences > Music Change 'Format settings' to 'Custom Settings' ? People have suggested that using a different format like FLAC or changing the "quality" setting fixes the error. Also, using a format like FLAC is lossless like wav but allows tags so should not throw an error.

Comment: Also, are these burned CDs or are they professionally produced from a record company?

Comment: The displayed messages were "Unable to play file. Advanced Streaming Format (ASF) demuxer is required to play the file, but is not installed. (Cancel/Find In Ubuntu Software)" and "Unable to Find Requested Software".

Comment: The .wav files are on my PC hard drive but are directly from original retail purchased CDs.

Comment: The pattern seems to be files taken from CDs I purchased in about the last four years, regardless of the original release date of the music. E.g. I can play the track "Broken Leg" by Bluejuice, which was released in 2009, but not the track "Survivor", by Destiny's Child, which was released in 2001 but which I purchased in 2019.

Comment: Do you have: `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed? Run the following command to check: `dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-restricted-extras` If this command does not list `ubuntu-restricted-extras` let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I got "dpkg: error: unknown option -1" I can't see "Edit" anywhere in the Rhythmbox menus. I know other file formats are available but I thought I'd see if there is a simple fix for me to be able to play them in the format they are all in.

Comment: That is an `l` not a `1`. Just copy and paste the command `dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Also, edit is at the top window menu.

Comment: Okay. I did try to copy/paste but it wouldn't do it for some reason. The "l" (that's a lower-case L?) in the terminal looks different to the one in your comment, i.e. different font? I just tried it with the "l" and got nothing - just a new prompt followed by blank space. Okay I see the "Edit" now but there is no "Preferences" in the drop-down menu for that. BTW I'm totally new to Linux (as in literally yesterday). Hang on, Edit has gone again. Where did it go? I can't figure this out.

Comment: That's okay. The window menu appears when you hover your mouse over the menu area. Because the command returned nothing, it is not installed. I will answer this question below.

Comment: I got Edit back by clicking on one of the top menu options. This is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is a bit advanced for me. I've only been using computers for about 40 years now, since I was age 10. It may need a bit of getting used to.

Comment: That's cool. Just copy and paste the commands so you don't have to type so much. Eventually the commands will become more familiar and then you'll understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .wav files are on my PC hard drive but are directly from original retail purchased CDs. The pattern seems to be files taken from CDs I purchased in about the last four years, regardless of the original release date of the music. E.g. I can play the track "Broken Leg" by Bluejuice, which was released in 2009, but not the track "Survivor", by Destiny's Child, which was released in 2001 but which I purchased in 2019.

It's not WAV files. It's ASF files. That's a lossy Microsoft format for music.

The CD probably containted two parts: One audio part, and one data-part with a lossy version of the music stored for playback. This also fits with the fact that it applies to some CD's, but not all.

When it's a pure Music CD, you actually copy the PCM audio when you drag it from the CD to your disk. When it's a data *and* music CD, you only copy the datafiles.

I would look into [ripping the CD in a proper way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867593/is-there-a-way-in-ubuntu-to-rip-a-cd-to-flac-and-add-replaygain-tags-automatical/867749) so that you get the actual PCM data from all CD's, not the inferior lossy files, that may be encumbered by DRM.

Answer (score 1):

[Rhythmbox uses gstreamer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/FAQ) to play music. The ASF demuxer is provided by the [gstreamer "ugly" plugins](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/asf/index.html?gi-language=c).

**First, run the following commands to enable the** [universe and multiverse repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58364/whats-the-difference-between-multiverse-universe-restricted-and-main):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

**Next, run the following commands to install the ASF demuxer** and the [restricted extras package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100148/discussion-on-answer-by-mchid-rhythmbox-wont-play-wav-files-off-of-some-newe).